# spark-submit docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-spark

I have a basic pyspark program and my directory looks like this:

```
application
|
|
| ... app.py
| ... Dockerfile
| ... requirements.txt
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

So I have created a dockerimage and I have pushed it to `AWS ECR`, and my docker image is present at a url like this: `123456789123.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

I am wondering now in AWS EMR, how can I use `spark-submit` to actually just execute `app.py` in the docker image that is in AWS ECR?

Am I thinking this correctly? Can AWS ECR image directly be run from `EMR` using `spark-submit`?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are placing the files in a docker container..Its not like your code is going to run on the docker container environment. But rather u want it to use the spark libraries on EMR. SO the docker container defeats the purpose

Comment: @Emerson then how should Spark applications be run on EMR? I have a github repo with a project that creates a docker-image of the code and everything else. Please help

Comment: Just upload the application(zipped or otherwise) to s3 and provide the s3 path

Comment: Let me rephrase that.. If its  a single py file.. Upload to s3 and provide the s3 path when running the job. Additionaly, If you have written additional libraries to use in your application.. Zip it up and refer to it in --py-files as an s3 path

Comment: @Emerson, what about this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-docker.html?

Comment: It seems like even AWS has a way to use Dockerfiel from ECR no?

Comment: @Emerson so my project (multi-file) is stored in a git repo. I am wondering what could be the best way to use EMR with this? Its all Pyspark

Comment: I believe its meant to be use an execution yarn enrionmnet  via a docker image. Im not sure if you can do a spark submit for an application on EMR pointing to a file in the image. Even in the example aws provided in the link, the main.py is actually on the master node.

Comment: @Emerson I see. So for my project setup, which is a github repo, what could be the best way to run somethign like this on EMR? Its a pyspark project with several files.

Comment: wat we do, is upload to s3 the zipped up pyspark code. The entry point may be a script(which wouldnt be zipped) , and the rest of the files would be zipped up and imported as libraries via the --py-files option. When we deploy the code we build the library and deploy to s3.

Comment: @Emerson why not just link your git repo to it? Is that not possible?

Comment: When you say link. What do you mean

Comment: @Emerson like CD/CI basically. I have a spark project on Github with Cd/CI enabled through Jenkins, I am wondering how to best use AWS to launch this spark proejc

Comment: Currently im guessing you build the container with the code as part of the CICD pipeline..  You could choose to pacakge ur libraries as send to s3 as part of your cicd pipline

Comment: @Emerson, does spark-submit take in a docker image? I thought you need a jar or py only

Comment: for python you can add zip files as --py-files